# PHP Code hinting not working in Dreamweaver CS5

Tags: flash-cs5, dreamweaver, code-hinting

I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver CS5, I have been using this for a long time, but this is the first time I am facing such issue.

Some of the code hintings are disbaled, like `$_SERVER`, `$_REQUEST`, etc..

Is there any option to enable these hints? I tried preference option though its disabled.

I am missing exactly this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [killersites.com](http://www.killersites.com/dreamweaver/images/dreamweaver-code-hinting.png))</sub>

Comment: Your files do have .php extension correct? And other code hinting still works?

Comment: Yes they are .php extensions and other hintings like html,javascript work well. please see the link above for the exact problem.

Comment: @rekire Thanks for helping me out on editing pal.

Answer (score 2):

Go to menu `Edit -> Preferences -> Code Hints` and then disable `jquery code 1.7`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code hinting is turned on in DW options correct? (sorry can't post pic as comment) [image: Dreamweaver Code Hinting options]

Comment: DW code hinting files are located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration\CodeHints\. Core PHP functions and definitions are in the \BuiltinCode\ subfolder, where as Superglobal definitions are in the \Descriptions\PHP_CORE files

Comment: Yes Pal it is enabled, everything is fine with that I have used all the possiblities i seen online.

Comment: Well if php hinting boxes are checked like in the picture I uploaded, and php/xml files are in the CodeHints folders mentioned in my comment above and its still now working then you may need to reinstall Dreamweaver, or at the very least see if you can locate the CodeFiles on the install disk and recopy them. If that still doesn't work you may need to take it up with Adobe

Comment: no problem. Yours is a truly strange issue, I've been using DW daily for years and never had any issues with code hinting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "preferences->code hints" and disable jquery code 1.7 and it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can solve the error by just simply disabling the jquery hinting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't exclude jquery, the solution is just to increase the delay, just 0.5.